# Dealing with Android's MediaPlayer while rotating screen, pressing Home Button or App is interrupted

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, activity-lifecycle, screen-rotation

I'm in a tricky part of the workflow/design on my app.

I have a MediaPlayer that runs into a Service. I want the music to stop when user leaves (BUT NOT CLOSES) the App. That is, the Home Button.

So I implemented MediaPlayer's `pause()` and `start()` methods into Activity's `onStop()` and `onResume()`, respectively. That is working fine when testing with the button and relauching the App, but it also happens when the screen is rotated due to the Activity's lifecycle.

So, how can I avoid this in a efficient / elegant way? The music mustn't be interrupted when device is rotated. I thought in overriding Home Button's click method, pause there the MediaPlayer and setting a global boolean flag to check in `onResume()` if MediaPlayer must be resumed. But this seems to me like a hack or so, not a good practice.

I'm wrong with this? Is there a better way?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Not that it is ideal, but have you tried putting it in a fragment and setRetainInstance(true) so that the fragment isn't rebuilt on orientation change?

Comment: It may work but seems worse that the "hack" I mentioned. I think I was looking for something like `onUserLeaveHint()` as kcoppock said. Anyway, thank you for taking the time! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options here:

If your minSdkVersion is at least 14, you can check the `isChangingConfigurations()` flag before stopping the media player:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (!isChangingConfigurations()) {
        // Stop the Media Player
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could watch for `onUserLeaveHint()`:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    // Stop the Media Player
}
```

Although that won't be called if another application is forcibly drawn to the foreground (e.g. a phone call comes in).

EDIT: As an alternative you might be able to rely on `onWindowFocusChanged()`. It is called with `false` when leaving the activity with Home or Back, but not on a configuration change. It should also be called when another activity is brought to front.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // Stop the MediaPlayer
}
```

As a side note, you should typically use symmetric lifecycle methods (e.g. instead of `onPause()`, `onStart()` use either `onPause()`/`onResume()` or `onStop()`/`onStart()`)

Comment: My minSDK is 9. I was looking to that method rigth now. That will do the work, but I still need to have a flag to resume music if needed, right? On the other hand, how could handle a incomming call? Maybe an audio focus listener? [Reference](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html).  I know that the system sends a intent when a call comes in, but if possible I want to avoid as much permissions as I can. Oh, and thanks for the note. Is there a especial reason or only to follow a structure? Thank you very much.

Comment: I've just added a third possibility. I'm not sure exactly at what point in the lifecycle it's called, so you'd just need to check into that and make sure it's at a point where you're bound to the service or however you're connected. As for the second point, those symmetric methods correlate to a particular state (`STARTED`, `RESUMED`) so if you don't follow that you could end up in an unexpected state. For example, if you stopped your media player in onPause(), and started it in onStart(), then your media player would never resume if a translucent window (e.g. dialog) appeared.

Comment: Wow, one never stops learning. I think `onWindowFocusChanged()` doesn't fit. Music may be playing between some Activities. Almost sure that `onUserLeaveHint() + boolean flag` is the solution. Let me some time to test and I'll mark this as Answer. Back to the incoming call, what about the handling? :) I know that wasn't on my initial question but didn't notice that possibility.

Comment: As far as the flag goes, I'd just check if the MediaPlayer is playing, and if not, in `onResume()` start it again. No need for a separate flag. Incoming call is just an example -- it'd be any Activity that could get brought to the front unexpectedly.

Comment: Thank you. I'm now looking for handling when something gets in, but my original question is solved! Tested and working.